# Find the size of inner rectangle rotated 45 degrees within another rectangle

Tags: trigonometry, rotations, rectangles

As picture, when rotation is 45 degrees, there are multiple combinations of w and h, but if the ratio w/h is known, how do I calculate the size of inner rectangle? Thanks.

P.S. the pink one is a square.

[image]

Comment: As it’s tilted at 45 degrees, each edge of the rectangle has length $\sqrt{2}$ times its extent in the $x$ or $y$ direction.  But the total $x$-extent is clearly just $2s$... the edges go from the left side of the square to the right and then back again.  So $(2\sqrt{2})s=2w+2h$.  You can take it from there?

Comment: @mjqxxxx I'm really poor at Maths, I tried your formula it does work though I cannot understand your explanation, sorry. And how about you post this comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Replace the words "extent" and "$x$-extent" with "projection" and "projection on the $x$ direction"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the figure provided, one can write

$ s = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (h + w ) $

Suppose $ \dfrac{w}{h} = r $ a given ratio, then

$ \sqrt{2} s = h (1 + r) $

From which

$ h = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{1+r} s $

and

$ w = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}\hspace{3pt} r}{1 + r} s $